# Jquery Click Function -

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69JG7/), my question is after first click things are working fine, but if again click on H3, the newclass is not getting toggled.

thanks for the help in advance

```
$('.recommendation-block > h3').addClass('newclass');
$('.recommended-product').addClass('hide');
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.recommendation-block > h3').click(function () {
        $(this).next('.recommended-product').toggleClass('active');
        if ($('.recommended-product').hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).closest('.recommendation-block > h3').toggleClass('newclass1');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the version of toggleClass which takes a switch param, also you need to target the `recommended-product` which is in the current context.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.recommendation-block > h3').click(function () {
        var $prod = $(this).next('.recommended-product').toggleClass('active');
        $(this).closest('.recommendation-block > h3').toggleClass('newclass1', $prod.hasClass('active'));
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gXky8/)

In your case, the `if` block is executed only in alternate clicks because the `hasClass` will return true only when the `active` class is added to the `recommended-product`

Comment: if i want to keep one option open and another one drop down, the newclass1 toggle is not getting applied, can you kindly help http://jsfiddle.net/69JG7/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.recommendation-block > h3').addClass('newclass');
$('.recommended-product').addClass('hide');
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.recommendation-block > h3').click(function() {
        $(this).next('.recommended-product').toggleClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('newclass1');
    });
});
```